# How to import a class and keep the same package directory structure?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I created a bunch of classes and packages in the USER namespace for prototyping.  Now I need to move all of these classes into a different namespace.  When I export/import the classes from the USER namespace to another namespace, the package directory tree is not created correctly.  For instance:

> Classes / Package1.SubPackage1.SomeClass

gets created in the namespace like this:

> Classes / Package1.SomeClass

I also noticed that it stripped off Package1. from the original object I exported.

What's the trick?

I used Ensemble's Studio for above...

Comment: You could try the methods in %System.OBJ, such as ExportPackage and Load or LoadDir

Comment: Which version are you on? I'm not aware of any bugs in this regard, but I'll have a look

Comment: @kazamatzuri - 2009.1 (Build 602)